# How is sorting done in cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am a newbie in Cassandra. 
Does Cassandra follow any specified sorting algorithm like `bubble sort`, `binary sort`, etc.? If not, How does it sort in order by command?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, or at least it shouldn't. In Cassandra you build your data model around your use cases. So if you want to retrieve sorted data you have to store it sorted. If you want the same data sorted in different ways, you store the same data multiple times sorted differently. There is a lot more to read about how Cassandra works, and I think every user of Cassandra should.

Links related to your question:

- https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSimplePrimaryKeyConcept.html
- https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompoundPrimaryKeyConcept.html
- https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateIndex.html

Getting started with Cassandra:

- https://academy.datastax.com/courses (the first two courses is a must do. You need to register but they 100% free)

Comment: They just say that if partition key is same using clustering keys all the data are sorted, but i want to know how they are sorted like do they follow any algorithm like bubble,binary sort to  sort all the values of clustering columns

Comment: In that case you need to look at the code as I don't think anyone but the developers can answer that. Look at memtables and the different compaction strategies. You can also try asking in the Cassandra dev mailing list. http://cassandra.apache.org/community/