# Sort a result in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, cql

I need to calculate the maximun of a sum in Cassandra. I only got the sum of each type without sorting the result. How can I do this? I can't use subquery in Cassandra and materialized views don't work with this.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263785/how-is-sorting-done-in-cassandra

Answer (score 1):

Sorting of data in Cassandra can happen only on the clustering column, not on the arbitrary result. For your query you need to perform sorting inside your program...

P.S. please take DS201 & DS220 courses from [DataStax Academy](http://academy.datastax.com/courses) to understand the differences between RDBMS and Cassandra.

P.P.S. please make sure that your aggregate queries are working only inside one partition, not in the whole table - it most probably will break if you add enough data.  If you're using DSE, then you can use DSE Search to perform aggregations (via faceting), and then sort results.